# How to Clean/Refresh Azure App Service environment

Tags: azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am running into problem, where my code is failing when when deployed to an existing azure App Service (.NET 6 ).

I am deploying the code from Visual Studio via publish from the project.

When I deploy my code to another App service instance it works fine.

Now i am in development environment and i can afford to deploy it to different environment, i am worried about if this happens in production environment.

What are my option to reset/refresh existing environment like brand new and clear everything like cache, temp folder etc ?

Answer (score 0):

same code works if you deploy as fresh application and it fails when you deploy to an existing application which means there are certain environment variable which are not allowing application to work as expected.

you can check these environment variable by navigating to advanced tools and check what is that causing this application to not work as expected.

Also, it makes much sense to enable logging either using "App Service Logs" or Application insights to understand the issue and correct it.